# Oracle: How to loop and find dependent/dependency between tables for doing insert/update operation for each tables?

Tags: oracle

I have a requirement where in I have to loop through all the tables in the ORACLE database, find the dependencies(constraints, relationships) and perform the insert/update operation for each of the tables.

There are solutions like, 
1) disable all the constraints and perform insert/update data in each of the tables. Disadvantage is that: if any error occurs while enabling the constraints, oracle perform implicit commit which cause, some of the tables get committed and unable to rollback.

2) We can do the Flashback database and restore it, but it has its own adv and limitation(as we can do it only from Oracle 10g onwards)

So, I am finding is there any way to just doing loop and find the dependent/dependency table and take care of circular dependencies too, and perform the insert/update operation against each table. Please provide your input on this query?

or
Is there any way to evaluate the errors well in advance without performing actual database insert/update operation in order to avoid the implicit commit issue?

Appreciate your input in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get you correctly, but I think you could consider using what is called Deferrable Constraints.

Sample table.

```
create table testdefer(
  id number
, msg varchar2(42) not null initially deferred
);
```

This DML commits successfully.

```
insert into testdefer values(1, 'foo');
insert into testdefer values(2, 'bar');
insert into testdefer values(3, 'baz');
commit;
select * from testdefer;

ID      MSG
-----   -----
    1   foo
    2   bar
    3   baz
```

Whereas this one

```
insert into testdefer values(4, 'quux');
insert into testdefer values(5, null);
insert into testdefer values(6, 'meh');
commit;
```

Rolls back all DML returning an error.

```
ORA-02091: transaction rolled back
ORA-02290: check constraint (HR.SYS_C0011594) violated

select * from testdefer;

ID      MSG
-----   -----
    1   foo
    2   bar
    3   baz
```

That way you could update your tables and defer constraint and referential integrity checking until the final step when you're done and are ready to say `COMMIT`.

For more details about deferrable constraints, refer to the section [Deferrable Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/datainte.htm#CNCPT522) in Database Concepts.

Comment: I agree, but our dbas are telling that deferrable constraints is not a ideal way of doing it. Is there any way to loop and get the table dependency and perform insert/update operation?